# Activating account via email with Laravel 3

Tags: email, laravel, account, laravel-3, activation

I am trying to verify user accounts via email using the new users email and a hash. Something is wrong with my routing as I get a 404 error when clicking on the link.

The URL I send out to the user looks like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/users/verify/<email>/<hash>
```

My entire users controller is registered...

```
Route::controller('users');
```

My function in my users controller is as follows...just trying to get my function to fire, but I get the 404 error.

```
// VERIFY NEW USER
public function post_verify($email, $hash) {
   echo "$email Acct verified with $hash!";
}
```

This seems very simple. My controller is restful. Why is it not routing correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: I also tried...`Route::post('users/verify/(:any)/(:any)', array('as'=>'verify_acct', 'uses'=>'users@verify'));` as a route, but still didn't work.

Comment: **SOLVED** The email address in the URL (or more specifically the "@" symbol) was killing the routing resulting in a 404 error. If anyone knows why feel free to comment. Simply changing the email to the username was successful.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is replace post method with get method in your controller:
get_verify($email, $hash) instead of post_verify($email, $hash)

```
// VERIFY NEW USER
public function get_verify($email, $hash) {
   echo "$email Acct verified with $hash!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are **sending** a **URL** to the user , So when they **Open** it they actually send a **GET** request !
in your **Controller** you are waiting for **POST** Requests :) So it **never** happens ! coz there isn't a **form** to be filled and posted by users ! 
as Aleksey mentioned change it as follows :

```
// VERIFY NEW USER
public function get_verify($email, $hash) {
   echo "{$email} Acct verified with {$hash}!";
}
```